# How can i use multi-husky robots with laser scanner in gazebo?

Tags: ros, husky, laserscanner, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and Gazebo. I am using ros indigo and gazebo 2. I am using husky to simulate the system in gazebo simulator.

I have used your package for multi-husky mentioned here: https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/2016/03/simulating-multiple-husky-ugvs-in-gazebo/

It works fine with me. But I have a problem in using the laser scanner and the Kinect. I think they are mounted on the robots but they are not publishing to any topic. I found the topics of the laser scanner (/scan) but the scanner is not publishing to it and I want to have a topic for each robot’s scanner. Also when I try to add the scanner in Rviz I can’t find it in the topics of each robot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267983/how-can-i-use-multi-husky-robots-with-laser-scanner-in-gazebo?/) by [Abdelrahman Ezz](https://answers.ros.org/users/31431/abdelrahman-ezz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably check your argument value in launch file.

arg name="laser_enabled"  and its value might set to false.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2017-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0